# Is there an expression for $(S/k)$ where $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: summation, infinity, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

Given that $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-1/12$ 
(for an explanation see this  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12) or this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww) from Youtube)

For example if $k=4$:

$(S/4)=1/4+2/4+3/4+1+5/4+6/4+7/4+2+9/4...$

Please edit to improve or if necessary!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632807/an-intuitive-reasoning-for-12345-1-12  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687431/1234-1-12

Comment: "Given that..." ? Where is **that** "given"?

Comment: Please see the links posted by lab bhattacharjee. I have also added a link to a video which should give you general idea.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: what is the function f(k) where (S/k)=f(k)?

Comment: What is $(S/4)$ if not $S/4$?

Comment: I don't know, that is my question.However, $(S/4)=S+something$ must hold. I **think** I have an answer though but I don't want to look stupid ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been hashed and rehashed *ad infinitum* (!) but, obviously,
$$
S=-\frac1{12}\implies\frac14S=-\frac1{48}.
$$
And at the same time, since $S$ is
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n,
$$
then, "obviously",
$$
S=\sum_{n\ \text{even}}\frac1n+\sum_{n\ \text{odd}}\frac1n\geqslant\sum_{n\ \text{even}}\frac1n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\frac12S,
$$
that is,
$$
-\frac1{12}\geqslant\frac12\left(-\frac1{12}\right)=-\frac1{24},
$$
which opens up some fascinating possibilities, such as, sooner or later,
$$
-1\geqslant0.
$$

Comment: I don't think it is valid to say that (S/k)=(S)/k. For example, (S/3)=(1/3+2/3)+1+(4/3+5/3)+2+...=1+1+3+2+...=S+sum_n=1^inf 2n-1

Comment: Maybe you did not fully get the take-home message of this answer so let me state it more explicitely: $S=-\frac1{12}$ is a convention, valid in a specific context and only as such. To play with it as if it was a *true* identity like $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2^n}=1$, say, can only lead to chaos. And your question falls squarely into this trap.

Comment: @Did. Great answer, indeed ! May I keep it and reuse ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Yes you can (proofs that $-1\geqslant0$ are always free of charge...).